# Python3: How can i select only weekdays from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a dataframe with sales data, named "visitresult_and_outcome".

I have a column named "DATEONLY" that holds the sale date (format yyyy-mm-dd) in string format.

I now want to make 2 new dataframes: 1 for the sales made in the weekend, 1 for the sales made on weekdays. How can i do this in an efficient way?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['dayofweek'] = df['DATEONLY'].dt.dayofweek
```

This will pull the day of the week out of your date attributes. Creating your other dataframes will just be a matter of slicing.

Comment: My dates are stored as strings, so i can't use the datetime module directly. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Convert the strings using pd.to_datetime.

df['DATEONLY']= pd.to_datetime(df['DATEONLY'])

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html